# How to redirect with jquery ajax and php response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response

I have the following ajax and php. I want to redirect the user to a another page depending on the result i output with a php script. Php successfully returns the json to browser, but i am somehow not able to get the response url back into the js ajax to make the redirection. It always redirects me to /undefined. What is wrong with my code?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../custom_scripts/anmeldung_zurueckziehen.php",
    data: { anmeldung_id: anmeldung_id },
    success: function(response){    
    //alert (response.redirect);
    if (response.redirect) {
        window.location.href = response.redirect;
    }else {
        // Process the expected results...
    }
    }
})
```

This is the php.

```
$arr = array ('redirect'=>true,'redirect_url'=>'https://mypage.de/no- 
access/');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: what is the value of response.redirect, can you add into the question ?

Comment: You should be able to work out what's going on just by looking at what you're getting `console.log(response)` - never use `alert(object)` as it's useless.  If response is an object, then go ahead, if it's a string (json formatted) then you'll need to parse it or have the server respond correctly.  The point is, it should be obvious by just looking at what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `dataType` property for `ajax` to decode the response:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "../custom_scripts/anmeldung_zurueckziehen.php",
    data: { anmeldung_id: anmeldung_id },
    success: function(response) {    
        //console.log(response.redirect);
        if (response.redirect) {
            window.location.href = response.redirect_url;
        } else {
        // Process the expected results...
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Wish this helps:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../custom_scripts/anmeldung_zurueckziehen.php",
    data: { anmeldung_id: anmeldung_id },
    success: function(response){    
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    if (response.redirect) {
        window.location.href = response.redirect_url;
    }else {
        // Process the expected results...
    }
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I knew it was something with the data type that i have to convert it somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this

**First way is  - Either use JSON headers in Php like below**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Above will return JSON string with json headers and jquery will automatically parse it for you and your callback function will have proper object.

**Second Way is - in javascript  use JSON.parse like below**

```
 JSON.parse(response);
```

Above will basically parse your json string into Javascript object

Make sure you don't parse when you have set JSON headers from backend.